# SQL select data between two characters in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, substring

I have data shown below. I'd like to retrieve the data between the underscores. The data either side of the underscore can be any length. I am select this data from a table with thousands of rows and will be amount other data being selected in the overall query. Can anyone help please.

Column name is d.ThirdPartyRef

```
2500_NEW_001
```

I have already selected the data from the left of the above field for another column using the below.

```
substring(d.ThirdPartyRef, 1, charindex('_', d.ThirdPartyRef)-1) as CarrierCode_DayNumber
```

Thanks

Comment: What database are you really using?  Your question is tagged MySQL but the code looks like SQL Server.  I changed the tag to sql-server, based on the idea that the code works.

Comment: Hi, that's right, its SQL server, cheers for changing.

Comment: Your expected result from 2500_NEW_001 ??

Answer (score 2):

You can use ParseName()

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,ThirdPartyRef varchar(500))
Insert Into @YourTable values 
(1,'2500_NEW_001'),
(2,'2500_OLD_002')

Select A.*
      ,Pos1=ParseName(Replace(ThirdPartyRef,'_','.'),3)
      ,Pos2=ParseName(Replace(ThirdPartyRef,'_','.'),2)
      ,Pos3=ParseName(Replace(ThirdPartyRef,'_','.'),1)
 From  @YourTable A
```

Returns

```
ID  ThirdPartyRef   Pos1    Pos2    Pos3
1   2500_NEW_001    2500    NEW     001
2   2500_OLD_002    2500    OLD     002
```

Comment: Interesting, haven't seen `PARSENAME` before - it looks like this isn't the intended usage, as it's designed to have a `sysname` passed as the first argument, right? But certainly looks like a neat way to solve this kind of problem, provided you have 4 or less "pieces" in the value you wish to split.

Comment: @3N1GM4 You are correct.  It is a little limited.  I definitely prefer my parse functions, but folks tend to resist UDFs regardless of their speed and functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that the values will contain exactly two underscores:

```
DECLARE @ThirdPartyRef VARCHAR(50)
SET @ThirdPartyRef = '2500_NEW_001'

SELECT  @ThirdPartyRef AS Value,
        CHARINDEX('_',@ThirdPartyRef) AS FirstUnderscore,
        CHARINDEX('_',@ThirdPartyRef,CHARINDEX('_',@ThirdPartyRef)+1) AS SecondUnderscore,
        SUBSTRING(@ThirdPartyRef, CHARINDEX('_',@ThirdPartyRef) + 1, CHARINDEX('_',@ThirdPartyRef,CHARINDEX('_',@ThirdPartyRef)+1) - CHARINDEX('_',@ThirdPartyRef) - 1) AS Result
```

Results:

```
/------------------------------------------------------------\
|     Value    | FirstUnderscore | SecondUnderscore | Result |
|--------------+-----------------+------------------+--------|
| 2500_NEW_001 |        5        |         9        |  NEW   |
\------------------------------------------------------------/
```

The `FirstUnderscore` and `SecondUnderscore` columns are just there to illustrate how the solution works.